# Should I use "pasinteco", "estinteco", or "paseo" to talk about the past?

Tags: word-choice

I already use the word *pasinteco*, or *pasintece*, to talk about something in the past. I recently read the word *estinteco*, then while reading in the dictionary, I found the word *paseo*.

When should I use each word?

I've already got part of an answer elsewhere, but I thought it would be a good question for this format.

Comment: JC Wells marks _paseo_ with an asterisk, meaning it's a recent coinage and less frequently used. That was in 1977, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are all essentially the same, and work as translations both of "the past" and "his/her past" etc.

*La estinteco* is "that which was." It forms part of the triad:

> *estinteco — estanteco — estonteco*
>
> that which was — that which is — that which shall be

*La pasinteco* is "that which has passed."

> *pasinteco — nuno — venonteco*
>
> that which has passed — the now — that which shall come

*La paseo* is an alternative term for the past. It comes (I think) from the [*Parnasa Gvidlibro* (1932)](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parnasa_Gvidlibro), which suggested many new words. It is very frequent in literary Esperanto. Otherwise it is used as the name of the grammatical tense (along with *prezenco* and *futuro*). Your use of it depends mostly on your attitude towards literary neologisms. Note however that it has the advantage that it avoids blurring the meaning of *-eco*.

Comment: JC Wells gives _preterito_ for _past tense_ in the grammatical sense.

Comment: The preterite is just one form of past tense.